# ANTLR: not match if a certain character follows

Tags: antlr, antlr4, vlang

Following code is completely valid in the [V](https://vlang.io/) programming language:

```
fn main() {
    a := 1.
    b := .1
    println("$a $b")
    
    for i in 0..10 {
        println(i)
    }
}
```

I want to write a Lexer for syntax coloring such files. `1.` and `.1` should be matched by `FloatNumber` fragment while the `..` in the `for`-loop should match by a punctuation rule. The problem I have is that my `FloatNumber` implementation already matches `0.` and `.10` from the `0..10` and I have no idea how to tell it not to match if a `.` follows (or is in front of it). A little bit simplified (leaving possible underscores aside) my grammar looks like this:

```
fragment FloatNumber
    : ( Digit+   ('.' Digit*)?  ([eE]  [+-]?  Digit+)?
      | Digit*    '.' Digit+    ([eE]  [+-]?  Digit+)?
      )
    ;

fragment Digit
    : [0-9]
    ;
```

Comment: When I try `a := 1.` and then `println(a)` on https://v-wasm.now.sh , I get an error. Are you sure `1.` is valid? Do you have a link to the V docs that says so?

Comment: @BartKiers Compiling and running this file with `v run test.v` works fine and it prints the expected result. I haven't found a detailed language definition yet (like for Nim).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then you will have to introduce a predicate that checks if there is no `.` ahead when matching a float like `1.`.

The following rules:

```
Plus
 : '+'
 ;

FloatLiteral
 : Digit+ '.' {_input.LA(1) != '.'}?
 | Digit* '.' Digit+
 ;

Int
 : Digit+
 ;

Range
 : '..'
 ;
```

given the input `"1.2 .3 4. 5 6..7 8.+9"`, will produce the following tokens:

```
FloatLiteral              `1.2`
FloatLiteral              `.3`
FloatLiteral              `4.`
Int                       `5`
Int                       `6`
Range                     `..`
Int                       `7`
FloatLiteral              `8.`
Plus                      `+`
Int                       `9`
```

Code inside a predicate is target specific. The predicate above (`{_input.LA(1) != '.'}?`) works with the Java target.